# Get all possible ordered sublists of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

Let's say I have a list with the following letters:

```
lst=['A','B','C','D']
```

And I need to get all the possible sublists of that list that maintain the order. Thus, the result must be:

```
res=['A'
     'AB'
     'ABC'
     'ABCD'
     'B'
     'BC'
     'BCD'
     'C'
     'CD'
     'D']
```

I had implemebted the following for loop, but an error occurs, saying that "TypeError:Can only concatenate str (not "list) to str"

```
res=[]
for x in range(len(lst)):
    for y in range(len(lst)):
        if x==y:
            res.appebd(x)
        if y>x:
            res.append(lst[x]+lst[y:len(lst)-1]
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst=['A','B','C','D']

out = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i, len(lst)):
        out.append( ''.join(lst[i:j+1]) )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than nested loops with redefined inner loop bounds on each go, you can [use `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to generate the bounds for you:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['A','B','C','D']

out = []    
for s, e in combinations(range(len(lst) + 1), 2):
    out.append(''.join(lst[s:e]))
```

[`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) conveniently produces all possible start and end indices from a single `range`, producing each set one at a time in your desired order. It also simplifies the code enough that the equivalent listcomp isn't too unreadable, allowing you to condense three lines of code down to one:

```
out = [''.join(lst[s:e]) for s, e in combinations(range(len(lst) + 1), 2)]
```

Either way, `out` ends up with the value:

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the closest to what you have got and will produce the desired result:

```
res=[]
for x in range(len(lst)):
    for y in range(len(lst)):
        if x==y:
            res.append(lst[x])
        if y>x:
            res.append(''.join(lst[x:y+1]))
```

The error you are describing mean that you are trying to add a character to a list:

```
lst[x]+lst[y:len(lst)-1]
```

lst[x] is a character and lst[y:len(lst)-1] is a list of characters and python does not know how to add it together. It can add a character and a string though using a join function.